# Spring Security - AuthenticationProvider not executing for each request

Tags: spring, spring-boot, kotlin, spring-security, firebase-authentication

I have created a custom Authentication Provider for Firebase. However, it doesn't execute for each (any) request. None of the breakpoints I placed were hit inside the provider, nor the user service.

Each request to the protected routes returns a 403 error when providing a valid token, while the other routes work fine.

The authentication provider

```kotlin
@Component
class FirebaseAuthenticationProvider(private val userService: UserService): AuthenticationProvider {

    override fun authenticate(authentication: Authentication?): Authentication {
        val token = authentication?.credentials as? String ?: throw BadCredentialsException("No Token Supplied!")
        val decoded = userService.decodeToken(token)

        val uid = decoded.uid
        val email = decoded.email
        val roles = Role
            .claimsToRoles(decoded.claims)
            .map { SimpleGrantedAuthority(it.name) }

        val userDetails = User(uid, email, roles)
        return UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userDetails, token, roles)
    }

    override fun supports(authentication: Class<*>): Boolean {
        return UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken::class.java.isAssignableFrom(authentication)
    }

}
```

The security filter

```kotlin
@Configuration
class SecurityConfig(private val authenticationProvider: FirebaseAuthenticationProvider) {

    @Bean
    fun filterChain(http: HttpSecurity): SecurityFilterChain {
        return http
            .authorizeHttpRequests()
                .requestMatchers("/api/v1/*/create", "/api/v1/*/update", "/api/v1/*/delete").hasAnyRole("EDITOR", "ADMINISTRATOR")
                .requestMatchers("/api/v1/users/**").hasRole("ADMINISTRATOR")
                .anyRequest().permitAll()
            .and()
                .csrf().disable()
                .authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider)
            .build()
    }

}
```

I've tried many fixes on the internet such as using AuthenticationManager and creating a bean to provide 'FirebaseAuthenticationProvider', but to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

You should configure the provider first:

```java
@Configuration
class SecurityConfig(private val authenticationProvider: FirebaseAuthenticationProvider) {

    @Bean
    fun filterChain(http: HttpSecurity): SecurityFilterChain {
        return http
            .csrf().disable()
            .authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider)
            .authorizeHttpRequests()
                .requestMatchers("/api/v1/*/create", "/api/v1/*/update", "/api/v1/*/delete").hasAnyRole("EDITOR", "ADMINISTRATOR")
                .requestMatchers("/api/v1/users/**").hasRole("ADMINISTRATOR")
                .anyRequest().permitAll()
            .build()
    }

}
```